# How to generate chart/graph on node.js as an html file

Tags: node.js, highcharts

I need to render a chart as a .html file on the node.js side.
Are there any libraries which can do that? 
I was doing some research, and every one of them is saving it as a .png file.
What I want to achieve is that I want to allow users to hover on chart etc. that's why I cannot use .png file

Comment: Just use a client-side chart lib such as [AMCharts](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4) or [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/). You can generate the markup on the server side but it's the client's job to render it.

Comment: My chart contains more than 20 series, each series got something about 50 records. Then I have to render almost this same chart 3 times more. That's why I want to move to the backend side.

I will test those libraries which you've provided, thanks. I'm using Vue currently, I'm not sure why this chart rendering is so slow

Answer (score 1):

You can use `highcharts-export-server` to generate a chart in SVG format, but the case with interaction is complicated - please check this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7058

However, I think the amount of data that you want to show on a chart is not so huge. Highcharts provide [boost module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module) and [dataGrouping](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping) in Highstock, which will effectively improve performance:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    boost: {
        seriesThreshold: 1
    },
    series: [...]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mhgraqbs/